# Firebase onAuthStateChanged interfers createUserWithEmailAndPassword.then

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password1)
.then(() => {
        var user_uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        db.collection(ll_collection).doc(user_uid).set({
          user_review: 0,
          number_of_reviews: 0
        })
})
```

It creates a document named after the user's id right after the account creation.

I also have another function on the same file that checks if an user is logged in or not:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.location.href = "/";
    }, 400)                 
  }
})
```

I had to set a timeout on this function, since the account is logged in right after the account creation. If I don't put the timeout, it is going to redirect to "/" right after the account creation without creating the document. It makes sense, since onAuthStateChanged is in realtime.

But is there another way I can redirect the logged in user on the page without interfering with the operation after the account creation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I typically only use `onAuthStateChanged()` and not the `then()` completion handler of the user creation.

So in that case both document creation and redirect would be in the `onAuthStateChanged` and you can synchronize there:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password1);

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if(user) {
        db.collection(ll_collection).doc(user.uid).set({
            user_review: 0,
            number_of_reviews: 0
        }).then(function() {
            window.location.href = "/";
        });
    }
})
```

If you only want to create the document when the user is new, you can check if they already have a document, or reject the document (re)creation in security rules.